# Macbook Air internal mic is bad for recording vocal music. Should I use an external microphone to pick up sound from the amp?

Tags: audio-recording, vocals, live-sound, macbook

I have a Macbook air which has a very bad internal mic to record vocal music, to be honest. I tried using an external mic of a headphone to record audio by keeping it near my Roland amp. This worked pretty well, but sometimes the headphone starts acting during Facebook Live and the audio goes real bad.

Is there any way (not a line-in or MIDI solution) in which I can use an external device to record from my amp? Will keeping a collar mic near my amp and connecting it to the mac help?

Comment: Other than product recommendation, I'm not seeing a real question here. If my inbuilt mic is bad should I use a better mic? Well… yes, obviously. If you don't want to get a decent mic that needs a decent preamp, then your choice is limited to whatever you can plug in directly.